# Why this line is using list(counts.items()): instead of dict(counts.item()):?

Tags: python

Isn't the key-value pair stored in the dict() now?

Why the code is going through a list but not the dictionary?

````
import string
fhand = open('romeo-full.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in fhand:
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in counts:
            counts[word] = 1
        else:
            counts[word] += 1

# Sort the dictionary by value
lst = list()
for key, val in list(counts.items()): # <----- This is the line
    lst.append((val, key))

lst.sort(reverse=True)

for key, val in lst[:10]:
    print(key, val)```
````

Comment: That `list()` is completely superfluous either way… In fact, the entire loop is. `lst = sorted(counts.items(), reverse=True)` would suffice.

Comment: I suspect the code was originally written for Python 2 and did something like `for key, val in counts.items()`. This already created an extra list, as `items()` returned a list in Python 2. When moving to Python 3, all instances of `x.items()` got changed to `list(x.items())` because `items()` switched to returning an iterator. Nothing changed, but now the unneeded `list()` is more obvious. Note that `dict(counts.items())` wouldn't work because it would create a new dictionary and iterate over just its keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counts.items()` gives you an iterable, that consists of tuples with keys mapped to their values. Here, the packing in a list is actually not needed as that returned iterable is, as the name suggests, already iterable.

So, yes you are iterating through the dictionary, but by using the counts.items() you avoid having to call `counts[key]` again and again, which would cause additional computations, while you can already have all that availab with the call to `items()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unpack `dict(counts.items())` into `key, val` here, because iterating over a `dict` just yields the keys rather than the keys and the values.